Can you safely cut a countertop wash basin to make it narrower?
The specs doc is saying it is made of natural and synthetic composites protected with a layer of super resistant polyester. https://rubi.ca/en-CA/bathroom/sanitary-wares/RMP1400R
The width is 20 3/8 and I need it to be 19 1/2"
Is is possible to cut it ? Is it commonly done ?


Where will the faucet be mounted (the diagram doesn't seem to show pre-drilled holes for one), and will there be room for a faucet if you remove 7/8" (assuming it would mount "behind" the basin)?

yeah that is my question too ...see below in the comments

why do you need to do this? ... have you considered embedding the counter top into the wall? ... the tap could be wall mounted

Yes, you can cut it.
You need to purchase or rent a handheld wet saw. You can purchase a diamond blade for a regular circular saw, but it makes a ton of dust. The blade still needs to be lubricated with a spray of water while cutting. Working outside is obviously prefered.
Use painters tape to cover the counter in an area a little wider than the base of the saw that you are using. (This prevents the base of the saw from scratching the surface.)
Mark your line to be cut on the tape. You can clamp a straight edge to guide the saw, but the cut is going against a wall and that is usually not perfectly straight either. If a backsplash is being put up it will cover any gap. ( unless you go wildly off the line) Caulk is used to fill any gap 1/8 inch or less. Have a good solid work surface and plan on supporting the piece being cut off so it doesn't crack when getting near the end. Sawhorses that are ok to have sacrificial cuts are a good idea. (Don't set the depth of the saw to cut all the way through the sawhorse)
If using the wet saw,( prefered), the hose connection will provide water. If you opt for just a diamond blade in a circular saw, be sure it is plugged into a GFCI outlet. Have a friend spray a little water in the front of the blade as you cut. Not too much, just enough to keep the blade lubricated and help cut down on dust. Cut slowly, but not at a snail's pace.
Always use proper personal protection for Face, eyes and skin.

I am curious why you are recommending the handheld wet saw. I am planning to upgrade a wet saw like this https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/mastercraft-sliding-wet-tile-saw-7-in-0556791p.html to 60" linear motion rods (already bought) . In theory this should be able to cut the entire lenght
If you look again at the profile of the sink/top you do not want to cut the front as you will eliminate the lip but on the other side the back (close to the wall) will be narrower and not sure if you can still squize a tap hole there in the remaining strip

@MiniMe so why ask if you know all the answers?

@MiniMe, I never mentioned cutting the front. I do not know where you got that idea. There may or may not be room for the faucet. that was not in the OPs question and if it is a concern, that will need to be addressed by placement other than the back of the bowl.  The handheld wet saw is the simplest and easiest tool for the job.  If you have purchased something to modify what you have, good for you, but it is not what would be an obvious choice for a homeowner to do a "one time" job.

@SolarMike -because I am not very confident in my skills and I never did this before. So I am looking for angles that I might have missed
RMDman You are correct, the reader can't guess what tools I have, I was just curious to see if using a handheld wet saw would have any advantages. I was also curious to see if there are any other tools that could be used and this is why I did not mention my tool. I am pretty tempted to outsource the risk to pay a pro to do it for me

@ minime, It is no different than cutting a piece of plywood. You would use the same skills, but different tools.  If you are bad at cutting plywood, you will probably be bad at cutting countertops. You can measure the size needed for a faucet and determine if it will fit or the placement be modified, or scrap the whole idea. I do not have info on your entire project.
